# Problem with Run project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a Android Studio Kotlin project with my custom library. 
If I build clean and rebuild project or if I delete `.idea` folder it is possible to run it. 
But if I change something in my Activity, fragment or another classes and Run it to my device build crash with error

```
 Unresolved reference: MainActivity
```

and all other my classes. 
If I clean and rebuild or delete .idea its OK for first build

I took screenshot of Build Output: [image: Build output image]

*Is there anybody who knows how to solved it? Thanks a lot*

Answer (score 0):

1- Please use from last version of Android Studio
2- please check this problem on Emulator . ( If your problem is resolved , you should change your USB cable or change your USB Port )

Comment: I use Android Studio 3.5.1

Comment: and in emulator is a same problem

Answer (score 0):

Any other advice , when I made any change in Gradle a build it firstime everythink is ok. If I try it again it end with error

```js
    > Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
    e: C:\Users\jirasek.ondrej\AndroidStudioProjects\NVMES\app\src\main\java\com\nvsp\nvmes\MainMenu.kt: (27, 38): Unresolved reference: DefMenu
    e: C:\Users\jirasek.ondrej\AndroidStudioProjects\NVMES\app\src\main\java\com\nvsp\nvmes\MainMenu.kt: (28, 27): Unresolved reference: DefMenu
    e: C:\Users\jirasek.ondrej\AndroidStudioProjects\NVMES\app\src\main\java\com\nvsp\nvmes\MainMenu.kt: (59, 30): Cannot choose among the following candidates without completing type inference: 
    @HidesMembers public inline fun <T> Iterable<???>.forEach(action: (???) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
    @HidesMembers public inline fun <K, V> Map<out ???, ???>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<???, ???>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
    e: C:\Users\jirasek.ondrej\AndroidStudioProjects\NVMES\app\src\main\java\com\nvsp\nvmes\MainMenu.kt: (61, 40): Unresolved reference: it
    e: C:\Users\jirasek.ondrej\AndroidStudioProjects\NVMES\app\src\main\java\com\nvsp\nvmes\MainMenu.kt: (65, 57): Unresolved reference: it
    e: C:\Users\jirasek.ondrej\AndroidStudioProjects\NVMES\app\src\main\java\com\nvsp\nvmes\MainMenu.kt: (79, 26): Unresolved reference: DefBtn
    e: C:\Users\jirasek.ondrej\AndroidStudioProjects\NVMES\app\src\main\java\com\nvsp\nvmes\MainMenu.kt: (79, 63): Unresolved reference: it
    e: C:\Users\jirasek.ondrej\AndroidStudioProjects\NVMES\app\src\main\java\com\nvsp\nvmes\MainMenu.kt: (80, 22): Unresolved reference: DefMenu
    e: C:\Users\jirasek.ondrej\AndroidStudioProjects\NVMES\app\src\main\java\com\nvsp\nvmes\MainMenu.kt: (107, 34): Unresolved reference: DefBtn
    e: C:\Users\jirasek.ondrej\AndroidStudioProjects\NVMES\app\src\main\java\com\nvsp\nvmes\MainMenu.kt: (111, 38): Unresolved reference: MainActivity
    e: C:\Users\jirasek.ondrej\AndroidStudioProjects\NVMES\app\src\main\java\com\nvsp\nvmes\MainMenu.kt: (112, 15): Unresolved reference: MainActivity
    e: C:\Users\jirasek.ondrej\AndroidStudioProjects\NVMES\app\src\main\java\com\nvsp\nvmes\MainMenu.kt: (120, 39): Unresolved reference: DefBtn
    e: C:\Users\jirasek.ondrej\AndroidStudioProjects\NVMES\app\src\main\java\com\nvsp\nvmes\MainMenu.kt: (129, 43): Unresolved reference: DefBtn
    e: C:\Users\jirasek.ondrej\AndroidStudioProjects\NVMES\app\src\main\java\com\nvsp\nvmes\MainMenu.kt: (131, 19): Unresolved reference: MainActivity

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
    > Compilation error. See log for more details

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: false babel: false -->
```